# C++ realloc() : invalid pointer

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am working a on a project and I am facing a problem I just don't know how to deal with.

There is no problem when I compile the project, but at the execution, I cannot even get into the main() function.... It crashes before entering the main(). Here's the stack :

```
#0  0x00007ffff2859cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff285d0d8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff2896394 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff29a4b28 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff28a10f7 in malloc_printerr (action=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff29a0d5d "realloc(): invalid pointer", ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4996
#4  0x00007ffff28a6192 in __GI___libc_realloc (oldmem=0x7ffff58fb840 <QListData::shared_null>, bytes=32) at malloc.c:2986
#5  0x00007ffff31f5e3e in QListData::realloc(int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff31f5efa in QListData::append(int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff32e2d8c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff32dee29 in qRegisterResourceData(int, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff3181eb3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff7dea13a in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdfc8, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffdfd8) at dl-init.c:78
#11 0x00007ffff7dea223 in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:36
#12 _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe1c8, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfc8, env=0x7fffffffdfd8) at dl-init.c:126
#13 0x00007ffff7ddb30a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#14 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007fffffffe32c in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I have already tested some things : creating a small program using Qt5 (more specifically Qt5Widgets), there is no problem (neither at the compilation or the execution)...
I upgraded gcc and g++ to version 4.9.
Also cleaned the code from all the dependencies that we do not use, but there is no sign of progress..

The weirdest thing about this is that none of my teammates encounter this problem, and when I use Ubuntu from my Virtual box from Windows, this problem doesn't even appear.

I am working on Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa.

Comment: Can you show at least `call_init()` from `dl_init.c`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr that's almost certainly internal to glibc. It looks like qt is screwing something up when the dynamic library is being loaded up. https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=elf/dl-init.c

Comment: Sounds like an example of static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: Do you have any static variables that have Qt types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like something is going awry inside of Qt, during the library's initialization. Based on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28788, I have a feeling that you've somehow mixed Qt4 and Qt5 libraries. (Or maybe different versions of Qt5 libraries. Whatever. You've got weird linkage issues.)

Use `ldd` to check to see what your final binary is linked against, and make sure that every Qt library listed is of exactly the same version.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! You were right, and I solved my issue.

In fact, I was using PCl (Point Cloud Library) and QT5. PCL needs VTK so I installed VTK6. There was then a conflict between QT4 and QT5. I downgraded VTK to version 5.8 and the conflict disappeared !

Lesson I learnt : the latest version is not always the best !

Thank you for your clues !